What does 幸せだと mean in this context?
This song is called snowdrop, by Luna Haruna. I don't understand how shiawase+da+to are connected to the sentence

すごく ありふれてて
すこし 退屈な 今日も
二度と来ない しあわせだと
明日は もっと 思えるかな


Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/104244/9831 Compare:「今日を...しあわせだと（明日はきっと）呼べる」「今日も...しあわせだと（明日はもっと）思える」

The lyrics go:

すごく好きなひとの すごくとなりにいる かけがえのないこんな奇跡さえ 気付けないでいた ぼくらの すごくありふれてて すこし退屈な今日も 二度と来ないしあわせだと 明日はもっと思えるかな

This whole part can be read as one long sentence.
「...二度と来ないしあわせだ」と is connected to 思える. The と is a quotative particle.
「すごく好きなひとの すごくとなりにいる かけがえのないこんな奇跡さえ 気付けないでいた ぼくらの」 and 「すごくありふれててすこし退屈な」 both modidy 「今日」.
「すごく好きなひとの すごくとなりにいる かけがえのないこんな奇跡さえ 気付けないでいた」 is a relative clause that modifies 「ぼくら」.
「二度と来ない」 modifies 「しあわせ」.
To show how each phrase is related to another:

「〔（すごく好きなひとのすごくとなりにいる）（かけがえのない）こんな奇跡さえ 気付けないでいた〕ぼくらの〔すごくありふれてて すこし退屈な〕今日も〔二度と来ない〕しあわせだ」と 明日はもっと思えるかな。

The basic frame of this whole sentence is:
ぼくらの今日をしあわせだと思えるかな lit. I wonder if I will be able to think of our today as a happy day
